# Quick-edit button in Drupal Commerce

Tags: users, commerce

I'm using Drupal 7 and Commerce Kickstart 2.0-rc1.
I can't find a way to remove the possibility for a user role to use the "Quick Edit" button in admin/commerce/manage-products . I tried using hook_permission() but, despite the permission is taken into account, the button is still here and still works.

Is there a clean way to remove this action from the drop-down list ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole "Products Listing" requires the "super permission" (a permission that grants all kinds of access, including the ability to quick edit) "administer products." I have filed a feature request in the Commerce Kickstart Issue queue that requests the quick edit button have a more granular permission.

http://drupal.org/node/1883280

Josh